# Creating a digital wallet using RoR, Stripe, Devise and CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

So, we have a currently setup web service which is essentially a Email-as-a-service which runs for free (beta). But, we are looking to move up and we want to be able to charge as Pay As You Go like MailChimp and so on.

So, the two of us still don't know whats the best way to tackle this.

Should we create like a digital wallet where the user adds in money (via stripe) and then we remove a little portion of that for every email they send.

So, we would love some guidance on what to do and how you recommend we achieve it!